# Woocommerce how to back up orders and customers from live site to localhost site

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi all I have just been getting myself involved in using Woocommerce, and what I was wanting to know is what people do when they want to get a copy of the customers and orders from live down localhost?

at the moment I am using local is to do all the site changes, then send up to staging for testing and if is all ok then deploy up to the live site.

thanks Scott

Comment: I use [wp db migrate pro](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/)

Comment: Thanks helgatheviking I do have Duplicator and Desktopserver, I know can do xml exports of products but not users and importing an xml like this would be ideal instead of downloading the whole site all the time.

Comment: If you have to migrate data between staging/live even remotely often this thing is worth it. (Not affiliated with them, just my opinion).